# In Protractor (Webdriver) does element.click() return promise or somehow can process error?

Tags: javascript, selenium, element, promise, protractor

I was wondering if element(by.css()).click() for example , returns a promise or somehow i can catch the error and assert against it. 
In my particular case i have unclickable component and i want to catch the error about that and assert that indeed this button is unclickable because this used has  got no permissions to click on it.

Thanks in advance.

That the whole code i can share because it's all i have written really ...

```
element(by.id('main_navbar')).$("li[name=sb]").$("a").click()
```

And this is the error.

```
 UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (276, 70). Other element would receive the click: <li name="sb" ui-route="/sb" ng-class="{active:$uiRoute}" class="ng-isolate-scope">...</li>
```

This one is a good error to assert against.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead test for whether the component exists and is disabled:

```
it('component has no permissions', function(){
    var unauthElement = element(by.css('#main_navbar li[name=sb] a'));
    expect(unauthElement.isPresent()).toBe(true);
    expect(unauthElement.getAttribute('disabled')).toBe(true);
}
```